# Wp eCommerce meta information search

Tags: wordpress, search, e-commerce

This is a [repeat of this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73158/wp-ecommerce-meta-information-search) as I get quicker answers on SO.

Out of the box, WP eCommerce does not support Meta search. This is a big problem if you are selling books online and need clients to be able to search by the most important Meta tag, Author!

Can someone please tell me how I could go about including the meta information search or is there a better plugin that does not cost an arm and a leg to search for meta information too?

**EDIT:**

I have since found a plugin that will do a better search called Relevanssi and Alexander Gieg extended it a little further with his own code:

```
add_filter('relevanssi_excerpt_content','wpscproductexcerpt',10,3);
function wpscproductexcerpt($content, $post, $query) {
if ( 'wpsc-product' == relevanssi_get_post_type($post->ID) ) {
    $content = $post->post_content . ( !empty($post->post_excerpt) ? " $post->post_excerpt" : '' );
    if ( 'on' == get_option('relevanssi_expand_shortcodes') ) {
        $content = do_shortcode($content);
    } else {
        $content = strip_shortcodes($content);
    }
    // The line below fixes a minor bug in Relevanssi 2.9.14 custom excerpt generating code:
    $content = preg_replace("/\t/", ' ', $content);
}
return $content;
```

}

I need to be able to extend this a little further now since I am user [Visser Lab's Custom Field's plugin](http://www.visser.com.au/wp-ecommerce/plugins/custom-fields/) to make up for the deficiencies of WP eCommerce and need to figure out how to include the meta information from this plugin?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you know about the [WordPress Meta Queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)? I don't really have time to check the WP eCommerce plugin's code, but basically if you can hook to the query that the plugin makes, you can add a custom Meta Query that will include your custom fields. The `meta_query` query parameter is an array or arrays, which one of them containing a `key`(custom field name),`value`(value to match against),`compare`(comparison operator),`type`(whether it's text,number,date,etc)

Comment: Hi Nikola. WP eCommerce makes use of WP's generic search. Should I then hook into WP's query for the search?

Comment: Yes - [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-search-results-to-custom-post-type#post-1671437) you can see an example on how to do that. Just modify it to your needs and you'll be ready :)

Comment: Add that as an answer Nikola and I will mark it accepted ;) Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

From what it turns out, WP eCommerce is using the default WordPress query for displaying it's search results. That's great because this makes it really easy to modify this query to fit our needs. Here is an example code:

```
function mySearchFilter($query) {
    // is_wp_ecommerce_search() is not an actual function - if you know how to check if the search is from WP eCommerce - you might want to do that, so that you don't modify the normal WordPress search
    if ( $query->is_search /* && is_wp_ecommerce_search() */ ) {
        $query->set('meta_query', array( array( 'key' => 'custom_key', 'value' => $_GET['custom_key'], 'compare' => 'LIKE' ) ) );
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
```

I'm not sure of an exact function for checking whether this is a WP eCommerce search, that's why the `&& is_wp_ecommerce_search()` is commented-out.

You will have to adjust:

1. `'key' => 'custom_key'` part - enter the name of your custom field that you'll be looking for.
2. `'value' => $_GET['custom_key']` - enter the value that you'll be looking for. I assume that it will be coming from a `$_GET` argument, but your case might differ.
3. `'compare' => 'LIKE'` - the link bellow will give details about the structure of the `meta_query` argument, but basically this will look for custom fields with value similar to the searched one.

You can find more details on the `meta_query` query argument at the [Class Reference/WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) WordPress codex page.